# Add childrow even if parent is null

Tags: mysql

i work in SQLyog and added a column to my salesquote sq table called accountpersonmapid of type int unsigned.
this id must map to my accountpersonmap apm where sq.accountid = apm.accountid

i have set up the foreigh key but obviously cannot save it because of the Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`clevva_live`.`#sql-7f8_737`, CONSTRAINT `salesquote_account` FOREIGN KEY (`accountid`) REFERENCES `accountpersonmap` (`accountid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) error

how can i get past this??

```
  SELECT sq.accountid,apm.accountid FROM salesquote sq
  LEFT JOIN accountpersonmap apm ON sq.accountid = apm.accountid
```

i do not have a apm.accountid for every  sq.accountid

any help please?

Comment: Have you allowed `sq.accountpersonmapid` to be NULL (and probably default to NULL)? If you do you'll be able to have `salesquotes` without a specified `accountpersonmap` but if you do specify one MySQL will still check that accountperson exists.

Comment: I have allowed sq.accountpersonmapid to be null :)

Comment: Excellent. Can you easily setup an SQLFiddle or something to demonstrate your problem? I'm not sure I've understood it completely...

Comment: this is the actual problem but the other posts are not helping :) MYSQL: Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Does your `salesquote` table also have an `accountid` column (as well as the `accountpersonmapid` that you added)?

Comment: yes both tables have an accountid field from there my sql where i found some values are null on the accountpersonmap side :)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you might have created the foreign key on the wrong field in salesquote. From the original question it looks like you've created it on salesquote.accountid rather than salesquote.accountpersonmapid, is that possible?

Comment: i tried creating it on that as well, but need it on the accountid. Ill get some one here to have a look thanks :)